# UICollectionView not scrolling to bottom on the first few items

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, ios10

[image]

I've been trying to create a chat interface that I can reuse. I'm almost done with the implementation, but there's something that keeps bugging me about it. If I start loading in messages like in the gif when I first load the interface you can see that after the 4th message there are 3 messages that don't scroll to the bottom. With the 8th being the first one that does finally scroll. This varies according to the screen size. On the iPhone 6s testing device it reaches the 9th message being the one that scrolls.

I'm using content inset as the method to keep the collectionview visible with the following code being run every time the frame of the UIToolbar at the bottom changes

```
toolBar.inputAccessoryViewFrameChanged = {(rect: CGRect) in Void()
    let navigationAndStatusHeight = self.navigationController != nil && self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent ? self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height : 0
    self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: navigationAndStatusHeight + 8, left: 8, bottom: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - rect.origin.y + 8, right: 8)
    self.collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - rect.origin.y
}
```

This code is run every time a new message is inserted:

```
func insertNewMessage(){
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [NSIndexPath(item: self.numberOfMessages() - 1, section: 0) as IndexPath])
        }) { (Bool) in
        self.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
    }
}
```

with the scrollToBottom function being:

```
func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool){
    guard self.numberOfMessages() > 0 else{
        return
    }
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.numberOfMessages() - 1, section: 0), at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.top , animated: animated)  
}
```

I'm currently running on this version of XCode Version 8.1 beta (8T29o) & iOS 10.1(14B55c)

Comment: My guess, may be your collectionView is overlapped by keyboard, hence the CollectionView frame is not equal to the view that you see on top of your keyboard but equal to the height of screen. As a result when you keep adding messages after 3, collectionView won't scroll because its contentSize is still less than its frame so scroll to item won't have any effect, but when continue adding messages and when you enter 8th message finally content size is greater than the collection view frame hence it scrolls. So my solution change the frame of collection when key board comes up

Comment: to start from the bottom of top margin to the to the top of input accessory view of your keyboard :) make sure you update the content size as well :) now when u add 4th message cell will go out of collection view frame self.collectionView.scrollToItem effect kicks in and hence cell will scroll :D

Comment: After every insertion the content size is getting updated, and I can actually scroll down manually when they doesn't scroll down by calling the scrollToBottom method. I'm always updating the content inset of the collectionView so that it always fits in the inputAccessoryViewFrameChanged closure. The closure gets called every time the frame of the inputAccessory is changed (using observers). I'm pretty sure its not an issue were the content inset is being calculated incorrectly. However if its the case please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem maybe when the collection view content size is too small, scrollToItem doesn't work properly. Try use this code

```
func scrollToBottomAnimated(animated: Bool) {
        guard self.collectionView.numberOfSections > 0 else{
            return
        }

        let items = self.collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        if items == 0 { return }

        let collectionViewContentHeight = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
        let isContentTooSmall: Bool = (collectionViewContentHeight < self.collectionView.bounds.size.height)

        if isContentTooSmall {
            self.collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: collectionViewContentHeight - 1, width: 1, height: 1), animated: animated)
            return
        }

        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: NSIndexPath(item: items - 1, section: 0) as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: animated)

    }
```